# Add two google maps with different callbacks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two google maps containers on my page.

the first - id="map" is just a normal "display map"
the second - id="map2" is a search map where the user types in the input and the map refreshes to where the user typed.

these maps use the same api key but their callbacks differ.

if I add both of the following get and error in console saying duplicate api calls

```
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but the callbacks differ for each maps usage?

so how do i go about getting both maps to work, because currently I either get the on to work then the other wont work

my code is as follows:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>

    <script>
    function initMap() {
      var paarl = {lat: -33.725853, lng: 18.988628};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        scrollwheel:  false,
        center: paarl
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: paarl,
        map: map
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script>
  function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13,
      scrollwheel:  false,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Don't use two google maps library request

the simplest way is  invoke the second  function inside the fist initMap

```
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var paarl = {lat: -33.725853, lng: 18.988628};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          scrollwheel:  false,
          center: paarl
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: paarl,
          map: map
        });

      initAutocomplete();

      }


    </script>
```

or eventually use a onload event for load the second