# (Google Map API) Geocode was not successful for the following reason: REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, button

I am new to this place and I desperately need help from experts here! D=

I tried to make a page that can generate dynamic numbers of google map. The webpage, however, keep showing `Geocode was not successful for the following reason: REQUEST_DENIED`.

I double checked my google API console and confirmed that the geocoding API and Javascript API are enabled. (I literally enabled all Google map API in the list...)

[My Google Map API List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sNJ0.png)

Can someone please take a look and tell me why? T_T

//------------------------------------------------\\

Below is my javascript and html button:

Javascript:

```
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIkey&callback=initMap"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=mapAddress"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- &callback=mapAddress -->

        <script>
        function mapAddress(mapElement, address) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        // alert(mapElement);
        // alert(address);
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 17,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    disableDefaultUI: true
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapElement), mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
        }
        </script>
```

HTML(Supposed to be php variable):

```
<button type="button" class="button_mapAPI" id="address_<?php echo $case["id"]; ?>"  value="<?= $case['location_detail'] ?>" onclick="mapAddress('map1', 'Hong Kong')"/>Map Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Did you add pay method at your API Console?, now is the pay :O

Comment: Hello  Joel Garcia Nuño. Yes, I did! I added a credit card to my account

Comment: try to load : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=places, and don't use 2 callbacks ( You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page )

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889362/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the problem was loading the scripts as async, remove it..

try that jsfiddle with your API KEY

```js
(function(){
 let mapElement = 'map';
 let address = 'SPAIN';
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 17,
          center: results[0].geometry.location,
          disableDefaultUI: true
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapElement), mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
     alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: ``Geocoding Service: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key``        This is the message i got and the result is still being denied...

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials , green check ?; May is not active yet

Comment: I really want to end the topic but the reality is I still can't fix the problem... Thank you for your effort in helping me with this issue but I think maybe there is some kind of error on my webpage. Anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: Are u at localhost?

Comment: Yes I am at localhost )=

Comment: May that solve the problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329874/googlemaps-api-key-for-localhost

Comment: Thank you very much for not leaving this noob ( which is me haha) alone T_T You are the best!

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the Billing for API Key? Google Maps is no longer free. You have to associate a credit card so that you can get billed if your site has requests that exceed the $200 credit they give you monthly for free.

Answer (score 0):

Nead to enable geocoding api that convert address to coordinates and it is a bit pricier, use coordinates instead of address and no need for Geocoding API

Comment: I wont lie, being new to google maps api this made no sense to me. Could you be more detailed with an example?

Comment: @RedBud is correct, and this is the related answer that I needed to sove the same issue. Without enabling the Geocoding API, you will receive the "REQUEST_DENIED" error in some situations. In my situation, it was using the Divi Map module, to search for an address to set for the Maps API to use.  Thanks RedBud.